# How to filter certain nodes to discover paths

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, nodes, shortest-path

I've been playing around with the Movie Graph dataset and I would like to find the shortest path between two actors but omitting the movie nodes (nodes either can have the label Person or Movie).

This query returns the shortest path from Kevin Bacon to Meg Ryan:

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((bacon:Person {name:"Kevin Bacon"})-[*]-(meg:Person {name:"Meg Ryan"})) 
RETURN p
```

I now want to exclude the movie nodes, but how? This is what I've come up with, but it doesn't yield any results, unfortunately:

```
MATCH path=shortestPath( (bacon:Person {name:"Kevin Bacon"})-[*]-(meg:Person {name:"Meg Ryan"}) )
WITH nodes(path) AS ns
WHERE 
  ALL(node IN ns 
    WHERE NOT node:Movie)
RETURN ns AS path_without_movies;
```

The query is executed, but only with this result:

> "(no changes, no records)".

Any idea how I can improve the query?

Comment: You are finding the Shortest Path first and then filtering it. If your shortest path has `Movie` node it will not return anything.

Comment: I should have realised that - thanks for pointing it out! Back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 1):

To filter **Nodes** on the **Path** by **Label** you can modify your query as follow:

```
MATCH (bacon:Person {name:"Kevin Bacon"}), (meg:Person {name:"Meg Ryan"})
MATCH path=shortestPath( (bacon)-[*]-(meg) )
WHERE 
  ALL(node IN nodes(path) 
    WHERE NOT 'Movie' IN labels(node))
RETURN path AS path_without_movies;
```

OR

```
MATCH (bacon:Person {name:"Kevin Bacon"}), (meg:Person {name:"Meg Ryan"})
MATCH path=shortestPath( (bacon)-[*]-(meg) )
WHERE 
  ALL(node IN nodes(path) 
    WHERE NOT node:Movie)
RETURN path AS path_without_movies;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your second query is that the keyword WITH creates a logical partition in the query.

So if you removed the line `WITH nodes(path) AS ns`, the following WHERE  would be applied during the match. With that line, the Cypher is finding the results of the match, and than removing results from that list. (normally this difference isn't noticeable, but shortestpath reduces the results, changing the final results)

As [Raj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56542242/6893866) points out, you can just move the extraction (`nodes(path)`) from the WITH to the ALL to avoid the partition.

```
MATCH path=shortestPath( (bacon:Person {name:"Kevin Bacon"})-[*]-(meg:Person {name:"Meg Ryan"}) )
WHERE 
  ALL(node IN nodes(path)
    WHERE NOT node:Movie)
RETURN nodes(path) AS path_without_movies;
```